# What is the Russian equivalent of the abbreviation "DevOps"?

Tags: перевод, информатика, сокращения

"DevOps" is a clipped compound of "development" and "operations". (Explanation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps))

I couldn't find an equivalent term in Russian.

Is it used without being translated as "DevOps" or unabbreviated as "Операции Развития" in Russian?

Or is there another abbreviation for this term in Russian. If there is, what is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The names of some programming methodologies such as DevOps, Scrum, Agile are essentially proper nouns and are treated accordingly in Russian. In written texts, they are often referred to in the original script, though sometimes transliterated into Cyrillic: дево́пс, скрам, эджа́йл. In speech, they are quite freely inflected just as if they were foreign city names or the like.

Comment: is it wierd to use "Операции Развития" ? can it prefessional understand you mean "devops" ?

Comment: @stackr I suppose not. Операции развития may make sense in some context as some generic development operations, but I doubt anyone will infer it stands for 'DevOps'. After all, we don't convert IBM to МДМ (Международные деловые машины) or ARM to УМССК (Усовершенствованные машины с сокращённой системой команд). DevOps is originally an abbreviation that turned into something not unlike a brand.

Comment: @stackr Development in IT sphere translates as "Разработка". And still previous comment is right.

Comment: Is "Операции Разработка" sounds more reasonable than  "Операции Развития" ?

Comment: @stackr Not in the least. I didn't bother to correct your translation of *development* because it wouldn't affect the principal thing, namely that DevOps is essentially a proper noun.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to evaluate this answer wheter it is correct or not, but it was very helpful. I will accept this answer in that manner. thanks.

Comment: @stackr The answer is certainly correct and sufficient. Another good answer would be a rewriting of this one in its essential/practical points.

Comment: "девопс" is totally known and understandable to the target group